# How to properly use checkIf with multiple jsonPath extractions

Tags: scala, gatling, jsonpath

I've got scenario that I send GET request which sometimes can return 404 and I don't want to report it as an error on the final reports.
Additionally if that request is successful I need to extract multiple values from json response.

Generally those 2 actions I want to use work for me fine when used independent i.e.

1. extract multiple json values from response:

   ```
   jsonPath("$..usrn").saveAs("usrn"),
   jsonPath("$..street_descriptor").saveAs("street_descriptor"),
   ....      
   )
   ```
2. Handle 404s:

```
  status.saveAs("responseStatus"),
  checkIf(session => session("responseStatus").as[Int] == 200) {
    substring(usualHeader).exists
  },
  checkIf(session => session("responseStatus").as[Int] == 404) {
    substring(errorHeader).exists
  }
```

But when I tried to combine those two actions what I was able to do, which could compile and actually extract data, was following code.
But I feel it could be done without such duplication

```
.check(
  status.saveAs("responseStatus"),
  checkIf(session => session("responseStatus").as[Int] == 200) {
    jsonPath("$..usrn").saveAs("usrn")
  },
  checkIf(session => session("responseStatus").as[Int] == 200) {
    jsonPath("$..street_descriptor").saveAs("street_descriptor")
  },
   ...
  checkIf(session => session("responseStatus").as[Int] == 404) {
    substring("404 error").exists
  }
```

I'm on Gatling 3.0.3

Comment: what do you want to have happen in the case where you get a 404 and the two session variables don't get set? Are you handling this case later in your scenario?

Comment: in case of 404 I'd like to skip next part of test scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use optional checks

```
.check(
  status.in(200, 404),
  jsonPath("$..usrn").optional.saveAs("usrn"), 
  jsonPath("$..street_descriptor").optional.saveAs("street_descriptor")
)
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was intending for but just realised that I could probably change my test logic a bit and use your proposition.